# OBJ-C: How to release object which is return from method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am confused for the memory warning of object which is returning from method.
This is my code.

```
-(void)returnHeaderView
{
  self.headerView=[[UIView alloc]init];
  headerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 955, 45);


  UILabel *fromLabel=[self returnLabel];
  fromLabel.frame=CGRectMake(400, 5, 200, 44);
  fromLabel.text=@"Open Time";
  [headerView addSubview:fromLabel];
  [fromLabel release];(in correct decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller)

 [self.headerView addSubview:fromLabel];
 [self.view addSubview:self.headerView];
 [self.headerView release];
```

}

```
-(UILabel *)returnLabel
{
UILabel *label= [[UILabel alloc] init] ;
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.font = FONT_TITLE;
label.numberOfLines=1;
label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
label.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

return label;

}
```

This is my two methods.
1.-(void)returnHeaderView.
2.-(UILabel *)returnLabel.

-returnLabel is returning label and the reference of UILabel object which is returned by method is pass to the fromLabel UILabel object of returnHeaderView method.
Then i release fromLabel object.

But it is giving a memory warning( 
in correct decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller).

So any one suggest me what is wrong in this code.
And How to release object which is returned by method.[image: Image is from my code which describes memory warnings generated by analyzing program.]

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312997/incorrect-decrement-of-the-reference-count-of-an-object-that-is-not-owned-at-thi

Comment: Apple's [*Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) is required reading for all Objective-C programmers. It completely answers this and many other important memory management questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make small change and leak removes and also autorelease self.headerView to remove other memory leak warning:

```
-(void)returnHeaderView
{
  self.headerView=[[[UIView alloc]init] autorelease];
  headerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 955, 45);

  UILabel *fromLabel = [[self returnLabel] retain];
  fromLabel.frame    = CGRectMake(400, 5, 200, 44);
  fromLabel.text     = @"Open Time";
  [headerView addSubview:fromLabel];
  [self.headerView addSubview:fromLabel];
  [self.view addSubview:self.headerView];
  //[self.headerView release];
}

-(UILabel *)returnLabel
{
  UILabel *label= [[UILabel alloc] init] ;
  label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  label.font = FONT_TITLE;
  label.numberOfLines=1;
  label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
  label.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
  label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  return [label autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `returnHeaderView` you don't actually retain `fromLabel`, therefore you don't own it and shouldn't release it there (the warning "incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller").

The best option is to autorlease the returned label: `return [label autorelease];` and let it live until the surrounding autorelease pool is drained. Note that this also means removing the `[fromLabel release];` call from your `returnHeaderView` method.

If this sounds complicated, use ARC as it's actually recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your `returnLabel` method returns an object with a retain count of 1, not zero as the compiler is suggesting.  I think you might just need to change the method name to give the compiler a hint about the ownership of the returned object.  Try changing `returnLabel` to `createReturnLabel`.  Then the method will conform to the [copy/create naming convention](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#auditing-of-c-retainable-pointer-interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the leaks by changing your code like:

```
-(void)returnHeaderView
{
  self.headerView=[[UIView alloc]init];
  headerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 955, 45);


  UILabel *fromLabel = [[self returnLabel] retain];
  fromLabel.frame    = CGRectMake(400, 5, 200, 44);
  fromLabel.text     = @"Open Time";
  [headerView addSubview:fromLabel];
  [self.headerView addSubview:fromLabel];
  [self.view addSubview:self.headerView];

  [fromLabel release];
  [self.headerView release];

}

-(UILabel *)returnLabel
{
UILabel *label= [[UILabel alloc] init] ;
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.font = FONT_TITLE;
label.numberOfLines=1;
label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
label.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

return [label autorelease];

}
```

Suggestion: The best way to avoid such leaks is using ARC.

Comment: He doesn't even need the retain and release if he adds the autorelease to `returnLabel`.  If he goes this way he should just add the autorelease so returnLabel returns an autoreleased object, and then not retain or release `fromLabel` in `returnHeaderView`.

Comment: @AaronGolden: he is doing some task on the returned `UILabel`. So there can be a crash if the `autorelease pool` is drained immediately after the return statement.

Comment: but the autorelease pool is certainly *not* drained immediately after `returnLabel` returns in OP's posted code!

Comment: @AaronGolden: Ya, that is ok. But that's not a recommended way. Always retain a returned autorelease object (take Ownership). Apple docs recommend this approach.

Comment: fromLabel is retained by `self.headerView` in `[self.headerView addSubview:fromLabel]`.  There is absolutely no reason to include the extra retain and release here.

Comment: @AaronGolden Check this code: `UILabel *fromLabel = [self returnLabel];` here `fromLabel` have an autoreleased object. And he is changing the frame adding text and lot of stuffs on an autoreleased object. You can't predict when an autoreleased stuff will be released. Also the calling function don't have the ownership of the object. When you add it as subview it's ok (the view will retain it) if you do like:`[self.view addSubview:[self returnLabel]];` it's ok. Else the best approach is to retain the autoreleased object after use release it. It's recommended !!!

Comment: You can absolutely predict when the autorelease pool will be drained.  If there's no `@autoreleasepool` or explicit creation of an `NSAutoreleasePool` nearby you're dealing with the pool that's created at the beginning of the current iteration of the run loop and drained at the end of the current iteration of the run loop.  What do you think is going to happen, that the autorelease pool will be drained by a background thread?  If that were the case even your retain immediately after returning from `returnLabel` wouldn't save you from the race condition.